# Search in logfile - exit code

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, control-m

I have some legacy softwares that I need to automate under Control-M. These job are under Windows 2008R2.

These jobs have an exit code 0 if they run ok, but also if they can manage some errors. I need to raise an alarm when a specific string is in the log.

The string is not in the output of executable.

I implemented another job for this. It goes to search a string inthe file and in "On Do Actions" I search for the statement.

To have the statement in the output I think to use something like a **grep**. I used:

- `findstr`

  ```
  findstr "myerrorcode" D:\Log\greptest_%%$ODATE..log
  ```
- `grep` under **cygwin**

In both case I have an identical situation:

- If the string is found, everythings is ok
- If the file is not found or cannot be open, grep or findstr return an exit code = 1. This is ok, because the job has to raise an error.

But the problem is: when the string is not found in the file, both grep and findstr have a return code = 1.

How can I discriminate the cases when the file cannot be open and when everything runs ok, but the sring in the log is not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `grep`'s exit status to detect the reason for failure. According to the [POSIX `grep` docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html), exit status section:

> ```
> EXIT STATUS
>
>    The following exit values shall be returned:
>
>    0    One or more lines were selected.
>    1    No lines were selected.
>    >1   An error occurred.
> ```

It's similar for [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Exit-Status) (consistent, but more specific):

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred. [...]  Other grep implementations may exit with status greater than 2 on error.

For example, in `bash`, you could use the `case` command to handle multiple branches like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# search for error code in file
grep code file

# store the exit status in variable err
err=$?

# test several cases
case $err in
    0) echo All good.;;
    1) echo Code not found.;;
    *) echo Error reading from file.;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this within Control-M easily:
Add in Job Tab "Action"

1. Add "On Do Action"
2. On: "Specific statement output"
3. Statement (as Control-M documentation state):

> A character string, from 1 through 132 characters in length, containing a statement from the job script file The specified string can be a portion of the statement.
>
> Statement character strings can each contain mask characters. Valid
>   mask characters are:
>
> ```
> * – represents any number of characters (including no characters)
> $ – represents any single character
> ? – represents any single character
> ```

4. Code:

> A character string, from 1 through 255 characters in length, to be
>   compared to the operating system’s response to the specified
>   statement.
>
> Code character strings can each contain mask characters. Valid mask
>   characters are:
>
> ```
> * – represents any number of characters (including no characters)
> $ – represents any single character
> ? – represents any single character
> ```

Example:
[On Do Action Control-M 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml7Ij.png)

Comment: I cant do this because the software is not returning output on std output or error. It just write a log file.

Comment: You can do a "cat" to the log so you can capture in the sysout

Comment: I think I will. A type in my case